# String interpolation in package.json variables

Tags: node.js, npm, syntax, package.json

I am maintaining an `npm library`. In its `package.json` I have a set of scripts that rely on the `config` field of `package.json`. Basically, I have a set of scripts, and each of them rely on a specific config that contains a `url` and a `name`.
I am looking for a way to interpolate `host` into each `url` field value.
Here's a snippet of my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "config": {
    "host": "host3",
    "first": {
      "url": "http://host3/.../swagger.json",
      "name": "first_service"
    },
    "second": {
      "url": "http://host3/.../swagger.json",
      "name": "second_service"
    },
    "third": {
      "url": "http://host3/.../swagger.json",
      "name": "third_service"
    }
   },
   "scripts": {
    "generate": "generate-script ...",
    "generate:first": "yarn generate -p $npm_package_config_first_url -o ./$npm_package_config_first_name",
    "generate:second": "yarn generate -p $npm_package_config_second_url -o ./$npm_package_config_second_name",
    "generate:third": "yarn generate -p $npm_package_config_third_url -o ./$npm_package_config_third_name"
   }
}
```

I am looking to do something like this:

```
  "config": {
    "host": "host3",
    "first": {
      "url": "http://$host/.../swagger.json",
      "name": "first_service"
    },
    "second": {
      "url": "http://$host/.../swagger.json",
      "name": "second_service"
    },
    ...
   },
```

I tried doing string interpolation the same way that `package.json` variables are referenced in the `scripts`, but it doesn't seem to work. Npm documentation does not have this info either.
I realize that this whole "scripts and config" approach may not be ideal but this is the only option for now, so I am trying to make it a little bit better.